# There is no user provider for user, symfony 3.4.37 and 4.4.3

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Since the upgrade to Symfony 3.4.37, I'm having this issue

There is no user provider for user "Mybundle\Myuser".

With version 3.4.36 and previous, it was working fine.

security.yml

```
security:
  providers:
    myprovider:
        id: myuser.provider
```

services.yaml

```
myuser.provider:
    class: Mybundle\MyUserProvider
    public: true
    arguments: 
        - '@arg1'
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: app.oneid.provider }
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Edit: The support class of my user provider:

```
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return MyUserProvider::class === $class;
}
```

Comment: Did you check this I think there was already a ```config/packages/security.yaml ``` file. So you need to putting everything in the latter resolved the issue.

Comment: Please let me know if this works in your case as I'm also doing the same mistake. @Pierre

Comment: @ArpitJainmy security.yml file is in app/config I don't have any config/packages folder, and when I downgrade to 3.4.36 everything works fine again

Comment: Looks like this might impact 4.4 as well.  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35435 Might want to add a comment to the issue indicating that 3.4 appears to have the same problem.

Comment: So the issue on github got closed after the poster discovered a problem with their UserProvider::supports method.  Consider updating your question with your supports method.

Comment: return MyUser::class === $class;  So the real mystery is why did this use to work?  But it does not really matter.

Comment: @Cerad yep all fine now, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserProvider supports method should be testing the User class, not the UserProvider.  So:

```
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return MyUser::class === $class;
}
```

What is interesting (to me at least) is that earlier versions of both 3.4 and 4.4 appeared to work.  The earlier code was either not calling the supports method or not checking the return value.  Kind of strange that this sort of problem took so long to fix.

I went ahead and posted an answer because I suspect other developers might run into this as they upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue on the Symfony 4.4.3 .The issue is on the method `supportsClass` on my custom user provider. A little explanation about how fix that issue:

Before (fails with the described exception):

```php
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $class === UserInterface::class;
}
```

After (works fine, use the final class):

```php
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $class === MyCustomModel::class;
}
```

I was checking the security component and I think that the issue is introduced in the next commit:
https://github.com/symfony/security/commit/0cfaf60c0666e8967590d0dada80caa7f9b61b02#diff-0cd860ec03e139a658ed3c258b615f21

Sincerely, I think that now it have the expected behaviour; but is breaking bad implemented custom providers.

I hope that it helps!